# Vue.js 2 page and element transitions with vue-router

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to achieve a simple page enter and leave transition (`Vue-CLI`). On the **leave transition** i'd like to animate some elements out before vue-router moves to the next component. But the `<router-link>` don't wait for the animation to be finished.

My attempt:

**App.vue:** `<router-view>` wrapped in `<transition ... >` handles page transition

**Component.vue:** `mounted()` set state to `this.show: true` and `<transition ... >` and `v-if` animate specific Elements in on render

When I navigate away from the component with the App.vue `<router-link>` the `beforeRouteLeave` gets called and sets `this.show: false` to animate out specific Elements and should then move on. BUT `<router-link>` renders the next component immediately without waiting...

In short I'd like to achieve smth similar to this http://animate.mhaagens.me/

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it solves all your problems, especially since I don't know exactly what behaviour you are looking for, but the transition effects in Vue provide **transition modes**.

`transition mode="out-in"` is perhaps what you are looking for. It waits for the first transition to end before starting the new one and is useful when transitioning between components. Check out [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html), they're very thorough and really good.